# heroku postgreslq push one table

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I have a demo heroku app running rails 4 on the free heroku tier with pgsql.

Somehow, probably due to a bug, a table appears to have been dropped, but I can't find anything in the logs that shows what happened.

Is there a way to restore JUST the missing table via the heroku command line, without blowing away the other data in the dev site? Or is it only possible to push the entire local database to heroku at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running PostgreSQL locally too, you can:

```
pg_dump -h localhost ... -t thetablename | psql $(heroku pg:credentials DATABASE)
```

to selectively dump that table locally and restore it to the remote DB.

Comment: I'm getting `psql: FATAL:  role "info" does not exist`